How to configure properly Global Post Script on Jenkins
I need to execute a script after every single build on my jenkins. I made a shell script that verify if theres a process of pdi (pentaho data integration) executing. If true, the script kill the process. I placed the file into the jenkins home folder but it never executes aparently.
Heres how I set the global post script plugin.

